# Why do people say "you could have done"?

Tags: grammaticality

An email from my American colleague says:

> If there is a transaction *you could have saved* data.

I don't quite understand his specific tone by the "could have saved". Why not just say "you can save data"?

Comment: I agree with your confusion. The sentence does not seem grammatical. Perhaps with more context it might make sense.

Comment: This is General Reference. If we assume the writer has a reasonable command of English, he can *only* mean *you could have **[some]** saved data*, as @ruakh says. Any other interpretation would have to assume the writer doesn't understand English verb tenses.

Comment: This could've been closed as GR for sure. Voting to close.

Comment: The sentence is perfect and makes sense as it should. If there's anything unclear in the sentence, it is because of a lack of understanding of the context (domain knowledge).

Comment: @Irwin: As pretty much everyone on this page has pointed out, we need further context. As it stands, this is not a question but a guessing game that's not helping anyone — least of all yourself.

Comment: I don't know either. that's why i asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways to interpret this grammatically.

> 1. "If there is a transaction, it is possible that you have data that was saved." (thanks to ruakh)
> 2. "If there is a transaction, by doing something different than a transaction you could have used less data resources."

An example of the second form:

> If you have a gold watch, you could have saved money. (i.e. by not having bought that watch).

The ambiguity comes from the fact that "save data" can mean different things:

- to store data
- to use less data
- to rescue data from danger (unlikely in this context).

Comment: So there is a grammatical description of "could have done". What's the difference with "could do".

Comment: "If you can eat, you could have learned to play the piano."  compared to "If you can eat, you could learn to play the piano."  In these two phrases, the only difference is the past versus present. Some people might take the past example to imply that it doesn't apply to the present situation. Also the past example implies that you could know how to play the piano in the present (if you had done something different in the past).

Answer (score 7):

Without more context, it's hard to be certain; but I'm guessing that what he means is this:

> If there is a transaction, it is possible that you have data that has been saved.

In other words, I'm guessing that it's "{could have} {saved data}", with *saved* being a participial modifier for *data*, not "{could have saved} data".

Comment: -1 It's not context but domain knowledge that's needed.

Comment: @Kris Domain knowledge *is* context.

Comment: @user867 Sorry, domain knowledge is not the same thing as mere context.

Comment: @Kris Fair point. What I should have said was "In this case, domain knowledge would constitute context, in that it would be information external to the quote under scrutiny that would enable it to be understood. Your comment that ' It's not context but domain knowledge that's needed' appears to be based on the assumption that the only possible definition of 'context' is 'the text immediately preceding and following the quote.'" Alternatively, I could have said "Domain knowledge *is* a kind of context," but that wouldn't have been as catchy.

Comment: @user867: FWIW, I liked your catchier version better.  Moreover, I believe it's an accurate statement (not that there aren't _other_ ways to provide context, but domain knowledge often is that proverbial missing piece of the puzzle).

Comment: @Kris: Re: "It's not context but domain knowledge that's needed": I don't know how you decided that. When I said "more context", I meant exactly "more context": the rest of the e-mail, or the rest of the e-mail chain. You know -- *context*. It's possible that, given the rest of the e-mail chain, my next response would be, "O.K., wow, turns out I need more domain knowledge, too." But I think I probably already do have enough domain knowledge: I have a lot of experience with databases, transactions, etc. (And anyway, that seems like a rather bizarre reason for a downvote!)

Comment: There are a few others around who have knowledge in the fields since the fields came to be, or actually earlier. So you may not want to think it's anything bizarre. Cheer up.

Comment: @Kris: Sorry, I have no idea what you're trying to say. You gave this answer a downvote on the grounds that it used the term "context" where you thought I meant "domain knowledge". (Right?) So, firstly, I clarified that no, I really meant "context": I think I probably *do* have the requisite domain knowledge; what I needed was context. And secondly, I commented that even if I *had* meant "domain knowledge", and had used the wrong term, this would be a bizarre reason for you to downvote the answer. Got it?

Comment: Let's get this right. Access to even the entire document (context) may not help to interpret the sentence; a background knowledge of what the sentence relates to (domain knowledge) will. HTH.

Comment: @Kris: I disagree. Even if Irwin's American colleague were describing a software feature that I myself had recently implemented, such that I had 100% complete, perfect domain knowledge, I would need the *context* (the rest of the conversation) in order to understand the sentence, because without the context, I would have no way of knowing that it *was* what he was describing. *First* context, *then* (perhaps) domain knowledge. And I still have no idea what your comment from 14:53 was trying to say!

Comment: @Kris: Ha, and I now see that you yourself used the phrase "lack of understanding of the context (domain knowledge)" in a comment to the original question. So, you're just a hypocrite. Never mind, 's cool. :-)

Comment: @Kris: "Access to even the entire document (context) may not help to interpret the sentence; a background knowledge of what the sentence relates to (domain knowledge) will." I think that domain knowledge _is_ a kind of context. Put another way, there's more than one context for [context](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/context).